# Open a website in new window and detect that redirect to another url

Tags: cocos2d-js, cocos2d-html5

In iOS, android I can show a webview and when it redirect to an url, I can detect it.

(like login via facebook, google ..vv..)

I want to do the same thing with `cocos2d-html5` or `cocos2d-js`. (**for web-browser**)

I just try below code but nothing happened

```
window.open('http://webdesign.about.com/',
            'open_window',
            'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
```

How can I tell web-browser open new tab for me?

**====== UPDATE ======**

My browser stopped all popups. my bad.

But I don't how to observe a `Window` object in javascript to know when it goes to new url.

I saw all thing about `window` at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp but I don't see something like that :(